# Send parameter in HTTP POST

Tags: android, http-post

I am using this code http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/ to send an image to my web server the code works fine but i want to be able to send some aditional parameters.

How can i send them , i tried constructing the url request like this http://www.mywebserver.com/postdata?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue but the web server never reconisez them.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you try to "recognize" the parameters in your PHP script?

Comment: I am not using PHP I am using a custom made webserver but it works with other forms posted like that

Comment: The params you pass in the URL are sent using GET. The forms use post. You'll most likely have to get these in different ways at the server.

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to pass them!

Comment: If you own the server, you have several ways of sending the parameters. The way I use the most is adding headers to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how did you program your custom server, but you passed the additional parameters the right way (via GET, not POST).

If you did it from scratch, by reading the HTTP protocol packets and interpreting them manually, then you'll have your GET parameters just after the requested URL at the first line, and will have to split the url by first using the '?' character to split the url from the parameters, then the '&' to split the different parameters into an array, and then split each parameter using the '=' character into a key and a value.

If that's not the case and used some kind of pyhon/Java/VB.NET library, please tell us which one..